# How to reset or change the Git user IntelliJ is authenticating with?

Tags: git, authentication, intellij-idea

I'm struggling to get IntelliJ to authenticate with GitHub using the correct user. Previously, I authenticated with a different user but had to change it. Now, IntelliJ always logs in with the first user and I cannot get it to change to my new user.

I have tried resetting passwords in 'Appearance and Behaviour' and have got only the correct user in the 'Version Control' section, neither have worked.

How do you change the git credentials that IntelliJ is authenticating with?

Referencing this as the error I'm getting:

> Remote: Permission to NewUser/GamesCore.git denied to OldUser. unable to access 'https://github.com/NewUser/GamesCore/': The requested URL returned error: 403

Answer (score 8, accepted):

On Windows 10:

Remove or update the Credentials stored in Windows Credentials at Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Credential Manager.

Comment: After 2 hours of research, this helped immediately in my case.

Answer (score 1):

on Mac:

you can search for Keychain access, and from here you can update the stored Intellij credentials.

You can also, try this on any of the OS for IntelliJ
`git fetch origin`.
If your credentials have expired it should ask for your username and token again.

Comment: This is short and simple solution.
Special thanks @Sarthak